# unhandled promise rejection: staticinjectorerror(t):MatRipple -> ElementRef]

Tags: angular

I recently upgraded to angular 6. On trying to load the app, I get this error:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(t)[MatRipple -> ElementRef]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatRipple -> ElementRef]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for ElementRef!
at t.get (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78)
at main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78
at xt (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78)
at t.get (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78)
at main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78
at xt (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78)
at t.get (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:78)
at jo (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:383)
at t.get (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:398)
at Os (main-client.js?v=uKfS6-YQlbK5hOKHois0Ghb7I_E4cHpAFDXv2Qk9aiw:405)
View_t_0 @ t.html:2
```

I dont know whats exactly wrong but after troubleshooting for sometime I discovered that the upgrade is having issues recognizing a angular material elements for example : mat-list-item.
This was working properly before the upgrade. Whats going on?

Comment: Did you change Angular Material version, or only Angular?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide, thanks for the concern. I updated angular material to the latest version as well (6....).

Comment: I didn't work with the Material 6 and it's why I can't say much. I think there are some changes, so I recommend to check the changelog or latest examples in docs